# Como hacer un pase de lista con jframe y mysql

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans, lista, jframe

Que tal, si me podrian apoyar estaria genial, estoy creando un proyecto sobre un control escolar en java netbeans con jframe conectado a mysql command line client, pero me he atorado al momento de pasar la lista, mi idea es tener un jframe que pida el id del alumno "ID_A" y al dar clic en el botón "Ingresar" en la base de datos "ControlEscolar" en la tabla "Alumnos" se incremente en +1 el campo "Asistencias" del alumno el cual se ingreso el id anteriormente en el jframe.

Espero haberme dado a entender, agradeceria mucho una respuesta o por lo menos si es posible hacer eso, tengo una idea en mente que es con un UPDATE y una condición WHERE pero aun no logro hacerlo funcionar, les agradeceria mucho de verdad.

Gracias y saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Te voy a mencionar al menos 3 formas.

- La primera es con java contar la cantidad de registros que tienes guardado en la tabla de la base de datos y cuando quieras ingresar un nuevo registro solo le sumas 1 al contador que tenias previamente y lo asignas al id.
- Otra manera seria tomar todos los ids almacenados y almacenarlos en un arreglo o lista, luego crear un numero aleatorio y verificar que no se repita en la lista, posteriormente una vez logrado esto, se lo asignas a la id y lo envias a la base de datos
- Tambien puedes ir a la base de datos y colocarle al campo id un atributo de AUTO_INCREMENT el cual se encarga automaticamente de hacer los 2 pasos anteriores que te mencione.

Comment: Gracias hermano, me ayudo tu comentario, ya lo resolvi, te agradezco